# Sending a column name and values as Parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I want to update an entry in Stored Procedure with the column name and column value that I pass as parameter, how can I do it.

Answer (score 2):

For something like that you will need to use Dynamic SQL

Something like

```
CREATE TABLE #Test(
        ID INT,
        Val VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #Test SELECT 1, '2'

SELECT  *
FROM    #Test

DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(MAX),
        @ParamValue VARCHAR(MAX),
        @Lookup INT

SELECT  @ColumnName = 'Val',
        @ParamValue = 'tada',
        @Lookup = 1

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @SQL = 'UPDATE #Test SET ' + @ColumnName + ' = ''' + @ParamValue + ''' WHERE ID = ' + CAST(@Lookup AS VARCHAR(MAX))
EXEC (@SQL)

SELECT  *
FROM    #Test

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Comment: Can you please make your code more in line with what I need to do

Comment: Can you also see with what is wrong with my update statement, probably I shouldn't be using the same syntax for both Varchar and Float updates.

Comment: At least try to understand the code, and if you have trouble, ask, and we can explain. If you understand the code, you would have learned something today at least.

Comment: why would some one want to create a temporary table and what is the use of Lookup variable

Comment: The temp table was mere as an example, you should be able to replace it with the table name you used in the Query above [TABLENAME]. The reason for using a temp table instead of a table variable is that the table variable will not be visible in the scope of the EXEC function. The use of the lookup is merely to filter your where clause, as you do not want to update the entire table, do you?

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
IF @COLUMNNAMEVALUEVARCHAR <> '' OR  @COLUMNNAMEVALUEVARCHAR is not NULL

IF @COLUMNNAMEVALUEFLOAT <> '' OR  @COLUMNNAMEVALUEFLOAT is not NULL
```